Python program for extracting games from PGN file based on tags (MacOS)
I would like to create a python script to extract games from a PGN file that is compressed using .pgn.zst, like the lichess.org database.
For example, one of the files is around 32GB compressed, and around 7 times more than that when uncompressed, so SCID won't work.
I need to use a program like zstdcat to directly work on huge compressed PGN files and run a python script on them. I need to make one that can search for tags like "WhiteElo" and "BlackElo" and make sure they match a specific value, and extract all games that match them to a file. I also want to select the time controls.
I need to create a python script that does the following:

Goes through the PGN file
Takes every game that have WhiteElo as 2500+, BlackElo as 2500+, and TimeControl as either "180+0", "180+2", "300+0", "300+3", "600+0", "600+5", "900+10", "300+0", or "30+20".
Extracts those games into another PGN file..


Is there any particular reason why it has to be a Python script? If you just want to process the games and extract those matching your criteria then you could use my https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/~djb/pgn-extract/ command-line tool to do that. You can pipe the output of the decompression program as input to pgn-extract and give pgn-extract a file of the tags you are interesting in matching. It will then output matched games, in PGN format, to a file of your choosing.

Right, I have just realized that you can use pgn-extract to do that.. If possible, could you please help me get pgn-extract running on MacOS? I only see Windows binaries on the website, and I have downloaded the .tgz file, yet I don't know how to run it.. Thanks

If you uncompress the .tgz file you will get a folder called pgn-extract. Open a Terminal window and cd into the pgn-extract folder (or open the Terminal in that folder). Then type make and the program should build as pgn-extract in that folder. To run it, type ./pgn-extract in that folder. The documentation describes the options to use for the filtering you want.
